# RKPaginator Params

Tags: restkit, tastypie

how can I use the "RKPaginator" with a custom "page paramter? My API doesn't provide a "page" param, it uses a pattern like this for pagination:

"http://my.domain.com/api/lists/?limit=5&offset=10"

"offset" is the param for the next page.

The JSON return form my API looks like this:

```
"meta": {
    "next": "/api/lists/?limit=5&offset=15",
    "total_count": 22,
    "previous": "/api/lists/?limit=5&offset=5",
    "limit": 5,
    "offset": 10
},
```

Or would it be easier to customize tastypie to handle requests like this?
"http://my.domain.com/api/lists/?page=1"
Which methods I've to override?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the RKPaginator::loadPage method with a objective-c category and calculate the offset from the page number and limit as shown in the following lines of code:

```
#import "RKPaginator+Tastypie.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation RKPaginator (Tastypie)

- (void)TastypieLoadPage:(NSUInteger)pageNumber
{
    [self TastypieLoadPage:(pageNumber-1) * self.perPage];
}

+ (void)load {
    method_exchangeImplementations(class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(loadPage:)), class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(TastypieLoadPage:)));
}

@end
```

And here comes the construction of the RKPaginator object:

```
RKPaginator *paginator = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] paginatorWithPathPattern:@"yourResource/?limit=:perPage&offset=:currentPage"];
```